# Matrix.frustumM causing problems not being able to set the near draw distance to zero

Tags: opengl-es

When setting the OpenGLES draw distance using Matrix.frustumM I notice that you can’t set the near draw distance to zero and any value less than 1 gives really weird distortion. Setting the near distance to 1 works fine most of the time but when the camera moves closer to objects than this distance it looks horrible because they are not drawn (or a portion of them is not drawn). Is there anything that can be done about this?
Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much can be done actually. The near and far clipping planes clip the pixels closer to `near` or further then `far`. Beside this the `near` is a bit special as it defines your field of view with the combination of the border parameters (`left`, `right`, `up` and `down`). So if you had a quad with same coordinates as those border if would be full-screen when exactly `near` away. Because of this the `near` plane can not be zero or even negative as for instance an object that would be at zero units away using a frustum would appear to be scaled infinitely.

Still you can use values smaller then 1 without having some strange artifacts. What you should do is look at some examples on how to define the `frustum` by setting a field of view. Generally you define your angle (a field of view) for one of the dimensions like 45 degrees in width, then you define your `near` and `far` as you please but both should be positive. Now use the trigonometry to compute the `left` and `right` using the `angle` and `near` and use the same values for `up` and `down` but scaled by screen (view) ratio. By doing so you will have no difference as in distortion when changing the `near` parameter.